PyCharm proxy issue
I use PyCharm IDE and i started to develop in Python language
install Python : OK
configure Proxy and test connection Proxy:OK

But when i want to import package --> 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
even by pip --proxy=https://<proxyhost>:<port>  install requests
Thanks in advance for your help
I checked the Class HTTPSConnection in connection.py
run connection.py
result :
from .packages import six
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

it seems that it's the same issue
perhaps this issue caused by firewall but i haven't privileges to get around it.
I have to solve this issue to continue my feature
Best regards
